# Disabling openssh client AAAA DNS queries

Tags: debian, openssh, ipv6

I have a Stretch-based desktop with IPv6 disabled, both as parameter in the kernel.

I have the ssh client from the `openssh-client` package, version  1:7.6p1-2.0nosystemd1, installed.

Upon debugging a DNS resolving problem, I did notice nonetheless the ssh client is doing IPv6 DNS related queries as the included `tcpdump` logs show.

My question, is, how to disable that behaviour?

PS. I am not asking whether it is a good or bad idea, just asking how to do it in a system that has already all IPv6 services disabled.

`tcpdump` logs when doing the commands `ssh server1 ; ssh server2`.

```
# tcpdump -n port 53
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on wlan0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
02:53:37.479073 IP 192.168.1.5.58296 > 192.168.1.1.53: 61011+ A? server1.home. (30)
02:53:37.479100 IP 192.168.1.5.58296 > 192.168.1.1.53: 4719+ AAAA? server1.home. (30)
02:53:37.487504 IP 192.168.1.1.53 > 192.168.1.5.58296: 61011 NXDomain* 0/1/0 (69)
02:53:37.493279 IP 192.168.1.1.53 > 192.168.1.5.58296: 4719 NXDomain* 0/1/0 (69)
02:53:37.493428 IP 192.168.1.5.60276 > 192.168.1.1.53: 31390+ A? server1. (25)
02:53:37.493455 IP 192.168.1.5.60276 > 192.168.1.1.53: 50392+ AAAA? server1. (25)
02:53:37.527879 IP 192.168.1.1.53 > 192.168.1.5.60276: 31390 NXDomain 0/1/0 (100)
02:53:37.535417 IP 192.168.1.1.53 > 192.168.1.5.60276: 50392 NXDomain 0/1/0 (100)
02:53:38.447390 IP 192.168.1.5.36155 > 192.168.1.1.53: 39363+ A? server1.home. (30)
02:53:38.447412 IP 192.168.1.5.36155 > 192.168.1.1.53: 4430+ AAAA? server1.home. (30)
02:53:38.455743 IP 192.168.1.1.53 > 192.168.1.5.36155: 39363 NXDomain* 0/1/0 (69)
02:53:38.461492 IP 192.168.1.1.53 > 192.168.1.5.36155: 4430 NXDomain* 0/1/0 (69)
02:53:38.461606 IP 192.168.1.5.39311 > 192.168.1.1.53: 45400+ A? server1. (25)
02:53:38.461631 IP 192.168.1.5.39311 > 192.168.1.1.53: 872+ AAAA? server1. (25)
02:53:38.493714 IP 192.168.1.1.53 > 192.168.1.5.39311: 45400 NXDomain 0/1/0 (100)
02:53:38.500353 IP 192.168.1.1.53 > 192.168.1.5.39311: 872 NXDomain 0/1/0 (100)
```

Proof IPv6 is disabled in kernel/grub:

```
$ cat /proc/cmdline 
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.10.5-antix.3-amd64-smp root=UUID=00c17984-859f-4197-8bd8-b346ddd092bd ro iommu=1 intel_iommu=on iommu=pt ip6.disable=1 intremap=no_x2apic_optout radeon.pcie_gen2=0
```

And also in `sysctl`:

```
$ cat /etc/sysctl.conf | grep ipv6
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
```

Also `/etc/gai.conf` is changed to prioritize IPv4.

Comment: [Red Hat explains](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/15863) that this happens because glibc is RFC2553 compliant, (now RFC3493) that there is no supported way to disable this behavior in glibc, and that the glibc maintainers aren't going to add one. Instead each application has to be reconfigured to use only IPv4 if this noncompliant behavior is truly desired. --- Of course, this is all in addition to the usual warnings about disabling IPv6.

Comment: This is sort of a jumpbox/desktop in a corporate IPv4-only environment, but yeah the usual warnings apply.

Comment: Ah, so the box itself is a workaround for the lack of IPv6 :)

Comment: @MichaelHampton `getaddrinfo`  is configured by the content of `/etc/gai.conf` where you can define the "priority"  of IP addresses between each other. And so you can make sure that IPv4 address are returned before IPv6 ones if you need this behavior, but then it depends of course on what the application does (if it does not stop at the first IP address returned).

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I know how gai.conf works. Changing it won't help here because the DNS AAAA lookups will still go out.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Indeed. `gai.conf` was already changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To disable IPv6 name queries in your `ssh`client, you can:

- call `ssh` in the command line with the `-4` option to only operate and do queries in IPv4;
- define then an alias as:

  ```
  alias ssh=`ssh -4`
  ```

If you have system administration of the machine, you can also disable the IPv6 functions/DNS queries in the `ssh` client system wide configuration file editing `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and adding the following configuration parameter:

```
AddressFamily inet
```

From `man ssh_config`:

> AddressFamily
>
> Specifies which address family to use when connecting. Valid arguments
>   are ''any'', ''inet'' (use IPv4 only), or ''inet6'' (use IPv6 only).